# angularjs ng-model setting default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I set a default value on an angularjs model? I'm looking for something like this if it's possible:

```
div.form-multiple(ng-model='story.r || []', form-multiple="form-multiple")
```

Right now `story.r` is just undefined. I would like to prefill it.

Here's my directive. The odd thing here is that it works just fine if $modelValue already has an array but does not if it's just undefined.

```
.directive('formMultiple', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel)
        return

      function pushIntoArray () {
        if(ngModel.$modelValue && elm.find('input:last').val() != '') { // this works fine
          ngModel.$modelValue.push(scope.formMultipleDefault)
          scope.$digest()
        }
        else if (!ngModel.$modelValue) { 
          ngModel.$modelValue = [scope.formMultipleDefault] // this block does nothing
          console.log(ngModel) // returns $modelValue undefined.
        }
      }


      pushIntoArray()
      elm.on('blur', 'input', function() {
        pushIntoArray()
      });

    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a directive, what you're looking for is:

```
ngModel.$setViewValue('something');
```

in the link function.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know how to set an arbitrary default for ng-model.

Comment: Do you mean sth like: ng-init='story.r=1'

Comment: @Harry do you mind explaining what you mean by that, if it's not exactly what I gave in my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear comment. I think setting it in the controller is unmaintainable. I would rather set it in the directive or the html.

Comment: It is `the` way to do it. Since you are using a directive, controller = directive in my post, but I was not aware of that before your edit. I will give you a more concrete solution now.